# How to include headers in first page of list of tables ,contents, etc

Tags: fancyhdr

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% Times Roman font
\usepackage{titlesec}% Times Roman font
\usepackage[english]{babel}
 \setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace{2.5in}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hspace{2in}\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hspace{2in}\Huge\bfseries}
%\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\Huge Contents}
\sectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\Large}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\large}
\chapterfont{\centering}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\fontsize{12}{15}\centering\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{25pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\centering\Huge\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{14pt}{}


\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1}
\begin{titlepage}

    \begin{center}
        \Huge
                \textbf{A Study and Validation of APSO for the tracking control of 2 Dof helicopter}



        \vspace{1cm}
       \begin{flushleft}
       \Large
         \textbf{\hspace{1.5in}G. Raaja\hspace{1.5in}11U232}
      \end{flushleft}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \large
       Dissertation submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of\\
       \vspace{.5cm}
       \large
        \textbf {BACHELOR OF ENGINEERING}\\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
\textbf {BRANCH: INSTRUMENTATION AND CONTROL\\}
of Anna University\\
%\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{v}
 %\fbox{\includegraphics{img-1.eps}}
 %\adjincludegraphics[height=5cm,trim={0 0 {.5\width} 0},clip]{img-1.eps}
%\end{figure}
        \vspace{0.8cm}  


        \large
       \textbf{April 2015\\} 
        \vspace{0.8cm}
        \textbf{DEPARTMENT OF INSTRUMENTATION AND CONTROL SYSTEMS ENGINEERING\\}
        \vspace{0.8cm}
        \textbf{PSG COLLEGE OF TECHNOLOGY\\}
        (Autonomous Institution)\\
        \textbf{COIMBATORE – 641004\\}  


    \end{center}
 \begin{center}
 \clearpage
        \pagenumbering{gobble}
        \Huge
         \textbf{A Study and Validation of APSO for the tracking control of 2 Dof helicopter}

        \vspace{1cm}

        \large
        Bonafide record of work done by\\
       \begin{flushleft}
       \Large

         \textbf{\hspace{1.5in}G. Raaja\hspace{1.5in}11U232}
      \end{flushleft}
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        \large
       Dissertation submitted in partial fulfilment of the requirements for the degree of\\
       \vspace{.5cm}
       \large
        \textbf {BACHELOR OF ENGINEERING}\\
        \vspace{0.2cm}
\textbf {BRANCH: INSTRUMENTATION AND CONTROL\\}
of Anna University

        \large
       \textbf{April 2014\\} 

\vspace{2.25in}
    \noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \makebox[3.1in]{\dotfill}  & \makebox[3.1in]{\dotfill}\\
    \textbf{Mr. K. Selva Kumar} &     \textbf{Dr. Jovitha Jerome}\\

    Faculty Guide & Head of Department\\
    \end{tabular}
    \hrule
    \vspace{1mm}
    \hrule height 4pt
    \vspace{1.5in}
     \noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
        \makebox[3.1in]{\dotfill}  & \makebox[3.1in]{\dotfill}\\
        \textbf{[Internal Examiner]} &     \textbf{[External Examiner]}\\

        \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{spacing}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents  

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{\listfigurename}}
\listoffigures
  \clearpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{\listtablename}}

\clearpage
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\section*{\centering Acknowledgement} 

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Acknowledgement}}\par

\end{spacing}
\fancyhead[L]{Acknowledgemnt}
\fancyhead[R]{}


\large
\par I would like to acknowledge many people who have helped me complete the project described in this dissertation. First and foremost, I express my sincere gratitude to \textbf{Dr.~R.~Rudramoorthy}, Principal, PSG College of Technology, for his kind patronage.\par
\vspace{.5cm}
I profusely thank and express my sincere gratitude to \textbf{Dr.~Jovitha~Jerome}, Professor and Head of the Department, Instrumentation and Control Systems Engineering, who has greatly inspired me through her powerful and motivational words and providing the necessary lab facilities.\par

\vspace{.5cm}
I am also grateful to have \textbf{Dr.~S.~Esakkirajan}, Associate Professor, \textbf{Mrs.~R.~Latha}, Assistant Professor (Senior Grade), \textbf{Mr.~D.~Jayaprasanth}, Assistant Professor and \textbf{Mr.~S.~ Natarajan}, Assistant Professor as my project co-ordinators whose inspirational words of guidance at all times prompted me to strive persistently.\par
\vspace{.5cm}
I express my sincere thanks to my supervisor \textbf{Mr.~K.~Selva~Kumar}, Assistant Professor, Department, Instrumentation and Control Systems Engineering, for his constant motivation and support during the course of my project. I truly appreciate and value his esteemed guidance and encouragement from the beginning to the end of this project. I am indebted to him for having helped me shape the problem and providing insights towards the solution.\par
\vspace{.5cm}
I also thank all the teaching and non-teaching staff for their cooperation to the students. My special thanks to all my friends for providing me good company in the lab. And I would like to thank all whose direct and indirect support helped me completing my project in time. I wish to express my gratitude to my parents, whose love and encouragement have supported me throughout my education.\par
\clearpage
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
\section*{\centering Abstract} 

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Abstract}}\par
\end{spacing}
\fancyhead[L]{Abstract}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\begin{spacing}{1}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\end{spacing}
\label{c1}
\fancyhead[R]{Chapter 1}
\fancyhead[L]{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{spacing}{1}
\chapter{Particle Swarm Optimization}
\end{spacing}
\label{c2}

\fancyhead[R]{Chapter 2}
\fancyhead[L]{Particle Swarm Optimization}

\begin{spacing}{1}
\chapter{Linear Quadratic Regulator}
\end{spacing}
\label{c3}
\fancyhead[R]{Chapter 3}
\fancyhead[L]{Linear Quadratic Regulator}

\begin{spacing}{1}
\chapter{Mathematical Modelling}
\end{spacing}
\label{c4}
\fancyhead[R]{Chapter 4}
\fancyhead[L]{Mathematical Modelling}

\begin{spacing}{1}
\chapter{Experimental~Results}
\end{spacing}
\label{c5}
\fancyhead[R]{Chapter 5}
\fancyhead[L]{Experimental~Results}

\begin{spacing}{1}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\end{spacing}
\label{c6}
\fancyhead[R]{Chapter 6}
\fancyhead[L]{Conclusion}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Bibliography}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{science,s}

\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: I do have few more doubts,   1) how to make all my section and chapter headings to Arial narrow 22 pt; 2)  how to make my chapter and section names to Arial narrow 20pt; 3) the command \nocite {*} is not working with this code......can u help me in rectifying those....

Comment: Then please accept the answer to mark the question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852). For your additional questions, please ask a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117)

Comment: I have made a follow up question and do I need to delete the old question.....because I have given a ur to this from that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reduced your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

To obtain what you want add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
```

so that the `plain` style is declared to be the same as `fancy` style.

Then add your `fancyhdr` for the ToC, LoF and LoT as you did for the other chapters.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\fancyhead[L]{\contentsname}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{\listfigurename}}
\fancyhead[L]{\listfigurename}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{\listtablename}}
\fancyhead[L]{\listtablename}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\listoftables

\clearpage
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\fancyhead[R]{Chapter 1}
\fancyhead[L]{Introduction}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Particle Swarm Optimization}
\fancyhead[R]{Chapter 2}
\fancyhead[L]{Particle Swarm Optimization}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]