# how to include \nocite{*} in a report

Tags: bibliographies

I have added the link of the code that is of my interest..please do visit,
[How to include headers in first page of list of tables ,contents, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224165/how-to-include-headers-in-list-of-table-contents-image-page-i-am-not-abl/224168?iemail=1&noredirect=1#comment526645_224165)                                                                                        1)in this code how to incorporate \nocite{*}, because when I include it shows various errors...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\fancyhead[L]{\contentsname}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{\listfigurename}}
\fancyhead[L]{\listfigurename}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\listoffigures
\clearpage 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{\listtablename}}
\fancyhead[L]{\listtablename}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\listoftables
\clearpage
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\fancyhead[R]{Chapter 1}
\fancyhead[L]{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Particle Swarm Optimization}
\fancyhead[R]{Chapter 2}  
\fancyhead[L]{Particle Swarm Optimization}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Bibliography}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{science,s}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

showing for example the errors:

> ```
> Missing \endcsname inserted ...acefactor \accent@spacefactor n2013397}{1}
> Missing \begin{document}. ...acefactor \accent@spacefactor n2013397}{1}
> Missing number, treated as zero ...acefactor \accent@spacefactor n2013397}{1}
> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup ...acefactor \accent@spacefactor n2013397}{1} 
> Undefined control sequence \bibcite{Ayd\OT1\i n20132456}{45}
> ```

the only code i got working of it is,

```
\documentstyle{report}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{science,s}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't show any error by my side. Can you include my example in your previous question with your additions?

Comment: actually i have a lot of problems when I use nocite{*}...it actually never ever worked for me until now in any of my codes except the below one...\documentstyle{report}
    \begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{science,s}\end{document}

Comment: " ... i have a lot of problems ..." -- and what, specifically, are these problems? Please don't ask others to play detective -- just list some of the error and/or warning messages.

Comment: Above mentioned are some of the errors  while I am trying to compile it.......

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.bbl` and `.aux` files?

Comment: @RaajaG Please edit the errors into the original question. That makes it easier for you and us to keep track of things.

Comment: One very very important thing you should look after: `\documentstyle` is obsolete for over twenty years. Using it makes LaTeX run in backwards compatibility mode. You should get huge warnings.

Comment: Yo Yo.......Thanks a lot @karlkoeller  .........

Comment: Yo Yo.......Thanks a lot @ Johannes_B  .........

Comment: one more doubt.....how to close this thread as answered..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) One very very important thing you should look after: \documentstyle is obsolete for over twenty years. Using it makes LaTeX run in backwards compatibility mode. You should get huge warnings.

2) try deleting the .bbl and .aux files

Both helps thanks guys................
karlkoeller &
johannes B

Answer (score 0):

The command `\nocite{*}` limits the **scope** to the **entire .bib file**.

Using `\nocite{<Keys>}` to limit the **scope** to the **specific reference** that you want to incude in the document.

Put `\nocite` command before `\printbibliography`.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you for your awesome package! I got it resolved as I found there's a small typo in my code. But I will join the chat :)

Absolutely the best & user-friendly key value package! You're my hero!